# numpy slice multidimensional array with colon

Tags: numpy, indexing, slice

I read an open source code that performing 4-dimensional array slicing using only 2 index values (one of them is `:`) as shown in the picture.
As I can understand that in the example,`a[:,2]` is equivelant to `a[:,2,:,:]`. Is that right? And where is the official document describing this usage (I could not find it). What about the case of `a[:,:,2]`? Is there any general rules in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at this: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#slicing-and-striding

Comment: Trailing : are automatic